# Bootstrap-table reset table sort icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I used bootstrap-table to populate my data from database but I encounter a problem on how to reset the table including the "sort" function and its icon. I used so far:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable('resetView');
$('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh');
```

On the http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/ but none of them work. I have a reset button but it doesnt work.

```
$('#resetBtn').on('click', function() {

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can destroy table and rebuil it, try to use :

```
$('#resetBtn').on('click', function() {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable('destroy'); //Destroy bootstrap table
    $('#table').bootstrapTable(); //Rebuild bootstrap table

    //You can do it in one line
    //$('#table').bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable(); 
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: $('#table').bootstrapTable('destroy');     is required when wanting to refresh tables with button clicks. Thanks Zakaria!

Answer (score 0):

`$('#table').bootstrapTable('removeAll');`